# double-quotes "\""?

Tags: c#, string, double-quotes

I'm trying to use quotes inside of quotes. It works inside of a text box, but not where I need the string. for example, the first line of code works, but I need the string to be a variable.

```
pictureBox1.Image = MediaLib.Get["chestarmor_105"];
```

but the next 3 don't. I ended up trying to use the richTextBox1.Text as a variable because it appears fine there with no luck.

```
string chestArmor = "chestarmor_105";
richTextBox2.Text = "\"" + chestArmor + "\"";
pictureBox1.Image = MediaLib.Get[richTextBox2.Text];
```

I've tried a number of different "" variations. What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The double quotes in the first line are a syntax artifact for the compiler to distinguish a string literal from a variable name. They are not there in the string; the string is `chestarmor_105`, without double quotes.

If you write

```
pictureBox1.Image = MediaLib.Get[chestarmor_105]; // no quotes
```

compiler will think that `chestarmor_105` represents an identifier; you enclose `chestarmor_105` in double quotes to tell the compiler that you want to use it literally as a string of 14 characters, not as a variable name. The compiler then removes the double quotes, and uses the value as a string.

This should work:

```
string chestArmor = "chestarmor_105";
richTextBox2.Text = chestArmor;
pictureBox1.Image = MediaLib.Get[richTextBox2.Text];
```